# Firestore query in function return

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have array in Firestore which I would like to use in many places. The best for me would be to have function with return like this:

```
function getWarehousesArray() {


    let db = firebase.firestore();
      var user = db.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email);
      var warehousesArray = new Array();
      return user.get()
        .then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {

            warehousesArray = doc.data().warehouses_array;
            return warehousesArray

          } else {
            swal("Error!", "No such document!", "error");
          }
          //return warehousesArray
        }).catch(function (error) {
          swal("Error!", error, "error");
        });

    }
```

and next:

```
var warehouses = getWarehousesArray();
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Is there an error? Does `warehouses` not contain what you expect it to contain? If so: please edit your question to show what you do with `warehouses` that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data from Firestore may need to come from the server, it is loaded asynchronously. The value you return from `getWarehousesArray` is not the actual array of warehouses (since that won't be available yet by the time `return user...` runs), but a `Promise` of those values.

To get the actual list of warehouses you can either use `async`/`await` (if you're targeting modern JavaScript):

```
var warehouses = await getWarehousesArray();
```

You'll need to mark the function that contains this code as `async`, as shown in this [MDN article on `async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

---

Alternatively for older environments, you can just unwrap the promise:

```
getWarehousesArray().then(function(warehouses) {
    console.log(warehouses);
    ... anything that uses warehouses needs to be inside this callback
})
```

Comment: Make sure `fn` should be `async` to use `await`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.
The working function is:

```
async function myFunction() {
  var warehouses = await getWarehousesArray();
...
```